# How do I move the instruction point in the Perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I would like to be able to (reasonably) arbitrarily set my execution point in the Perl debugger. E.g., moving immediately prior to an if from the body of the if and setting a variable.

Rummaging around the perldebug(and perldebguts and the perl debugger POD) page suggests that this kind of functionality is either not supported or not documented.

Comment: I am trying to imagine what you want to do, but can't. I will guess instead.  B::Util or B::Hooks::OP::Check may be helpful; edit the optree and set the next op to the one that you want to execute; or hook an op and run code when it is executed.  A custom runloop may also be helpful.  But basically, you are on your own here; time travel is not a feature of perl5db.

Comment: Not time travel. I'm looking to arbitrarily set the point of execution time to a given location, *without much regard* for the sanity of doing so.

Comment: Custom runloop sounds good then.  What you want to do is very strange, though, which is why it's not implemented.

Comment: For what it's worth - I want to do exactly the same thing in perl. For background - I successfully ran a big section of code, it worked fine, the next section  had a problem almost immediately so I'd like to step through that section without having to re-run the time-consuming first section of code again, that I already know runs properly.  

I know I've worked with other tools that allow this.

Answer (score 1):

A cumbersome workaround would be to add labels and conditional `goto` statements throughout your code. But depending on how badly you want to emulate this feature, it might be worth it.

```
POINT1: $GOTO="";      # $GOTO is our fake variable that we only set from the debugger
($a,$b,$c)=(1,2,3);
POINT2: $GOTO="";
if ($a < $b) {
    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
    if ($a > $c) {
        goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
        print "foo\n";
    } else {
        goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
        print "bar\n";
    }
    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
 } else {
    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
    print "nothing\n";
    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
 }
```

Sample debugging session:

```
$ perl -d debuggoto.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.28
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(debuggoto.pl:1): POINT1: $GOTO="";      # $GOTO is our fake variable that we only set from the debugger
  DB<1> n
main::(debuggoto.pl:2): ($a,$b,$c)=(1,2,3);
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:3): POINT2: $GOTO="";
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:4): if ($a < $b) {
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:5):    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:6):    if ($a > $c) {
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:10):               goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<1>
main::(debuggoto.pl:11):               print "bar\n";
  DB<1>
bar
main::(debuggoto.pl:13):           goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<1> $GOTO="POINT2"

  DB<2> n
main::(debuggoto.pl:3): POINT2: $GOTO="";
  DB<2> $c=0

  DB<3> n
main::(debuggoto.pl:4): if ($a < $b) {
  DB<3>
main::(debuggoto.pl:5):    goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<3>
main::(debuggoto.pl:6):    if ($a > $c) {
  DB<3>
main::(debuggoto.pl:7):        goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<3>
main::(debuggoto.pl:8):        print "foo\n";
  DB<3>
foo
main::(debuggoto.pl:13):           goto $GOTO if $GOTO;
  DB<3>
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<3>
Use `q' to quit or `R' to restart.  `h q' for details.
  DB<3>
```

I wonder if it would be possible to build a debugger that uses this idea.

Comment: Hunh. I wouldn't want to *manually* muck with the source to that level, but building an automated source modify&run debugger...now there's an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what exactly this would achieve, but I bet a custom runloop that skips ops you don't care about until you start caring again might solve your problem.

A good runloop to cargo-cult is [Runops::Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Runops::Switch).  Remove the switch statement and write a function that skips ops until you are on the one you want to run; then just call into the normal runloop to actually run that op.

Relevant code: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RGARCIA/Runops-Switch-0.04/Switch.xs

This is all handwaving, I have never written a runloop before.  The goto idea in another post is also good, but this involves writing less code.

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints can only be set on the first line of a statement.

Comment: I'm not looking to set a breakpoint. I want to move my execution point - the instruction pointer of the Perl VM.

Comment: What Paul is asking for is not what breakpoints do. While the program is paused, Paul wants to point at a specific line and say, "Resume running right here, now. Don't run anything more beforehand." A breakpoint doesn't let you skip over code or re-run code you've just passed. Moving the IP does.

Answer (score -1):

This can't be done with the existing debugger.

Comment: Wait a second, so far every answer is "no" and I get voted down?  Really?

Comment: Your answer wasn't "no." Your answer only told us what it is that you don't believe. That doesn't sound very confident. So you don't actually know the answer, and you have no alternative to suggest. Your answer wasn't useful, and was therefore worthy of a negative vote. (I thought -1 was enough, so I did not vote on it myself.) Besides, the other answers weren't "no," either. It wasn't a yes/no question. It was a "how" question. If you don't know how, and you don't know that it's impossible, then what contribution will your answer really make?